# Bloco catch mostra como undefined a uma variável

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema na hora de mostrar o valor de uma variável dentro do bloco **catch**. Ele simplesmente não imprime na tela o valor da variável **$sql**, aqui o código:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "meudb";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO minhaTabela (firstname)
VALUES ('John')";
// use exec() because no results are returned
$conn->exec($sql);
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $sql ."<br>".$e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

O erro ocorre exatamente no bloco **catch** quando tento imprimir na tela o valor da variável **$sql**, aqui nesta parte:

```
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $sql . "<br>". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Na tela aparece o seguinte:

**Quando tudo corre bem:**

New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: 1

**Quando algo dá errado,**

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ‘root’@‘localhost’ (using password: YES)

Não aparece na tela o valor de **$sql** que seria a consulta a MySQL. E no IDE aparece que **$sql** é undefined

– **O certo seria que apareça assim:**

**INSERT INTO minhaTabela (firstname) VALUES (‘John’)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ‘root’@‘localhost’ (using password: YES)**

Qual seria o erro que estaria cometendo?

Comment: a variável `$sql` não está sendo criada globalmente.

Comment: Nossa grande erro, muito obrigado!

Comment: Embora @thrnk esteja certo, não pense que as variáveis devam ser criadas globalmente para serem acessadas em um bloco `catch`. O que ocorre é: para que uma variável seja acessada em um bloco `catch`, ela deve ser declarada em um escopo acima do bloco `try`.

Comment: e como seria feito isso nesse caso @LucasSamuel? Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Respondi a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variáveis dentro do escopo local de um bloco `try` não podem ser acessadas fora desse escopo, como em um bloco `catch`, por exemplo. Para isso, você deve declarar essa variável em um escopo acima do escopo onde se encontra o bloco `try/catch`.

Em seu código, declare a variável `$sql` antes do bloco `try`. Então, você poderá acessá-la dentro do bloco `catch`.

Comment: é isso o que eu fiz sim. Declarei ela embaixo da variável $dbname; assim:
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "meudb";
$sql = "INSERT INTO minhaTabela (firstname)
VALUES ('John')";

Comment: Sim. Eu só fui mais específico sobre os escopos das variáveis.

Comment: Entendi @LucasSamuel, é isso mesmo, agora com o seu comentário não volto a errar pois você foi realmente mais específico.